# Minecraft world generation differs using exact same seed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I looked on the forums and stumbled upon an interesting seed and decided to try it out. Firstly installed this on my server with the following details:

> Seed: -7531061490504685328
>   Type: Large Biomes

At `/tp -986 33 -2560` there should be a dungeon with a skeleton spawner. Instead, it was not there. I thought I would try it locally. Created a single player world on my laptop, with the exact same details, and at `/tp -986 33 -2560` there was indeed a dungeon.

At this point, I closed my laptop, and decided to go on my main pc to check out the complete seed first before I place it on my server again.

I created a single player world on my PC with exactly the same details as my laptop. I did `/tp -986 33 -2560` and there was no dungeon to be found!

Tried this back and forth on my laptop and pc and everytime the dungeon is there on my laptop, and not om my PC, it's driving me insane.
**For both PC and Laptop, exact the same:**

```
[11:12:54 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.6.11 (through bootstrap 5) started on windows...
[11:12:54 INFO]: Current time is Apr 4, 2015 11:12:54 AM
[11:12:54 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 8.1'
[11:12:54 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.3'
[11:12:54 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
[11:12:54 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_20'
[11:12:54 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
[11:12:54 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'
```

Both PC and Laptop eventually running **Minecraft 1.8.3**. No mods, no texture packs, all clean installs, clean .minecraft folder. Same account, same java runtime details.

---

Eventually I want to run the version with the dungeon on my server, anyone have a clue how I can achieve this.

***UPDATE***

Adding a little bit more info:

server.properties

```
spawn-protection=16
max-tick-time=60000
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
gamemode=1
enable-query=false
player-idle-timeout=0
difficulty=1
spawn-monsters=true
op-permission-level=4
resource-pack-hash=
announce-player-achievements=true
pvp=true
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=LARGEBIOMES
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=false
max-players=20
network-compression-threshold=256
max-world-size=29999984
server-port=25565
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=false
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=true
generate-structures=true
online-mode=true
max-build-height=256
level-seed=-7531061490504685328
use-native-transport=true
motd=A Minecraft Server
enable-rcon=false
```

Screenshot of the world with dungeon:

[image]

Screenshot of the world without dungeon:

[image]

Link to the [forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/seeds/2386590-awesome-1-8-3-seed-15-desert-temples-11-villages-7), so maybe you can try it out yourself.

Comment: You could always generate the world on your PC and then move it to the server... But this would just be against the point of your question.

Comment: I expect you've checked this, but it is worth making sure you have structures enabled in the world generation options. If they're enabled on one and not the other that might explain the differences.

Comment: I am indeed going to transfer the world to the server, and start just on my laptop. Also, I did check structures, they are on.

Comment: This is just a conjecture, but perhaps it has something to do with the Unix timestamp...

Comment: @DorianDore no, that eliminates the purpose of the seed. It doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after much testing I finally figured out what is causing the problem, but I have no clue why this. The only way this dungeon appears is when you play `Single Player` mode and with `Allow Cheats ON`. There is no other way you can get this dungeon spawned in.

This actually boggles my mind because I thought these settings had no influence on the actual world generation, but apparently they do.

Also, I don't think there is an option in the `server.properties` on a server to set this setting, so it's basically impossible to have this dungeon on a server. Only way for me to do this is to create the world in Single player, go to the spot and load in the chunks, and then transfer the world onto my server.